# SSDT - Ignoring partition function changes

Tags: sql-server, database-project, database-partitioning, sql-server-data-tools, sql-server-2012-datatools

I'm trying to publish a database project, which also contains a partition function.
My destination databases have different (date) values which I do not wish to modify, although SSDT/SqlPackage always attempts to re-create the Partition Function and needless to say - all tables that use the PF.

I have checked the following options:
IgnoreObjectPlacementOnPartitionScheme & IgnorePartitionSchemes
([http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa833291(v=vs.100).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa833291%28v=vs.100%29.aspx))
but still getting the recreation attempt.

Running both VS2012 (latest SSDT) and VS2013

I've attached a sample project to demonstrate the behavior:
http://www.fast-files.com/getfile.aspx?file=73666

Comment: What is your reasoning for having different schemas on different environments?

Comment: These are not different schemas, only different partition function values. In prod we have a running "sliding window" which changes the date values every month. The Database project is not affected by these changes.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think I've managed to get this resolved -
Seems like VS UI ignores the "Ignore Partition Scheme" checkbox, however, when specifying in SqlPackage manually it works.
Added this to a SqlPackage execution: **/p:IgnorePartitionSchemes=True**

Hope it helps whoever got stuck on the same issue